# Em que região de Portugal se troca o "v" pelo "b" na língua falada?

Tags: pronúncia, português-europeu, regionalismo

A troca a que me refiro é, por exemplo, falar "baca" ao invés de "vaca".

Já há algum tempo que não a ouço, mas antigamente ouvia essa troca ocasionalmente quando ia ao Porto. Seria um dialeto?

Comment: Acho que grande parte da região norte

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O *v* 'é trocado' pelo *b*, ou rigorosamente falando, o *b* e o *v* são ambos pronunciados *b*, numa região que inclui todo o norte de Portugal e se estende para sul pelos distritos de Viseu, Aveiro e Coimbra. Ou pelo menos era assim. Creio que a pronúncia de *v* como *b* vai sendo cada vez mais rara. No resto do país o *b* sempre foi pronunciado *b*, e o *v*, *v*.

Agora se isto é um dialeto? De acordo com a definição dos linguistas uma língua é constituída por uma coleção de dialetos. (Talvez alguns classifiquem à parte o dialeto escolhido para norma-padrão.) A pronúncia do *v* como *b* o é (ou foi) uma das caraterísticas mais emblemáticas do dialeto, ou dialetos, do norte de Portugal. Os linguistas têm classificado o português de Portugal em dois a uma dezena de dialetos. Mas estes distinguem-se apenas por sotaques diferentes e umas poucas palavras próprias. Para pôr isto em perspetiva, [um artigo na wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialetos_da_l%C3%ADngua_portuguesa) lista dez dialetos de português em Portugal e 16 no Brasil.

Comment: 16 dialetos no Brasil?  Preciso rever a definição de dialeto com urgência. Eu sempre achei que as diferenças entre uma e outra região do Brasil fossem "regionalismos".

Comment: Também eu pensei isso durante muito tempo. E o mesmo para as regiões de Portugal. Dialetos havia em Itália e na Alemanha.

Comment: @Jacinto em Braga e Famalicão ainda se usa muito o *b*.

Comment: Para quem quiser *oubir* http://cvc.instituto-camoes.pt/hlp/geografia/som14.html

Comment: Por vezes ocorre o fenómeno de _hipercorreção_, que é a substituição de “verdadeiros” sons B por V em falantes que estão a corrigir demasiado o seu “problema” de betacismo. Uma amiga que viveu em Aveiro chegou a ouvir “vonveiros” em vez de “bombeiros”.

Comment: @JúlioReis Uma amiga dessa zona também me contou a história da *Votãozinho*, uma menina que não queria pronunciar *botão* 'incorretamente'. Mas creio que isto era mais frequente no passado. Nenhum dos meus amigos do norte pronuncia o *v* como /b/.

Comment: @Jacinto, asseguro-te que muito boa gente diz B em vez de V. É extremamente comum, e aliás as pessoas não deviam ter complexos com isso. Desde que escrevam bem, podem falar como entenderem. Todas as pessoas têm pronúncia de algum lado.

Comment: @JúlioReis Eu sou completamente a favor de cada um falar com o seu sotaque. Se os lisboeta podem dizer *orâlha* por que é que os bragantinos não hão de poder dizer *binho*. Estava apenas a constatar um facto. Os meu amigos são todos relativamente novos; não sei se isso não fará diferença.

Answer (score 8):

A troca do “v” pelo “b” é uma característica do falar de diversas regiões portuguesas situadas a norte do Tejo e está bem viva. Mas não é a única diferença de pronúncia, nem as diferenças dos diferentes falares ou dialectos do português europeu se resumem à pronúncia de alguns sons. 
Existem ainda diferenças de léxico, de formas de tratamento e até gramaticais (no norte interior português, a segunda pessoa do plural “vós estais”, “vós ides” em vez de “vocês estão”, “vocês vão” ainda predomina).

Outras diferenças dialectais bastante óbvias do português europeu são:

-» a pronúncia “ei”: pronunciado como “ei”, em grande parte da metade norte de Portugal, “ê” no sul e “âi” na região de Lisboa;

-» a distinção clara das sibilantes (as consoantes “s”, “z”, “j” e “x”) nalgumas zonas de Portugal, mas não presentes, por exemplo, no famoso “s” beirão: “caja” em vez de “casa”, “o-jolhos” em vez de “o-zolhos”; e a existência em Trás-os-Montes da distinção entre “x” e “ch” (pronúncia de “ch” em “Chaves”, tal como em “Chau”).

Também é de notar que **todas as variedades da língua** estão igualmente correctas, e todas **têm características dialectais que a diferenciam**, **incluindo o chamado “português-padrão”,** utilizado na televisão e influenciado pelos dialectos/falares de Coimbra e Lisboa.

Agora, saber **o que define um dialecto** ou até mesmo uma língua **é um problema bastante controverso e subjectivo**. Não existe consenso entre os linguistas, por exemplo, se o galego e o português são línguas "irmãs" (com a mesma origem) mas distintas, ou meramente dialectos ou variantes da mesma língua. Há quem diga que uma língua nada mais é que “um dialecto com um exército e uma marinha”, ou seja, uma língua com uma nação politicamente institucionalizada, uma língua oficial. Isto quer dizer que, frequentemente, a definição de um idioma como língua ou dialecto, ou de um falar como pronúncia ou dialecto é meramente política ou social (neste caso, relacionada com situações de prestígio ou identidade própria). Podemos pensar no caso do mirandês, por muitos anos considerado um dialecto “inferior” do português, quando, na realidade, tem uma origem distinta e é tão aparentado do português como o é o espanhol (castelhano), sendo que poderá ser considerado um dialecto, sim, mas de outra língua, o ameaçado asturo-leonês, falado na região de Miranda do Douro e nalgumas províncias do norte de Espanha.

O que é certo é que a língua portuguesa é falada de várias formas distintas não só em todo o país mas também por todo o mundo, e as particularidades regionais são e sempre foram parte dela.

Comment: +1 por *e está bem viva*

Comment: Em Portugal, o mirandês hoje é considerado não só língua, senão língua *oficial*.  Que pena que este ano morresse tal vez o defensor mais importante dessa língua, Amadeu Ferreira.

Comment: Para única resposta, está aqui uma bela peça... estou impressionado.

Comment: Relendo a resposta, achei-a excelente.

Answer (score 6):

Esta troca parece uma influência direta do espanhol, onde a pronúncia do *b* e do *v* é como *bê*. Ao dizer um nome que contenha a letra *B* ou *V* é possível ouvir a pergunta: "con *b* de buro o *v* de vaca" (pronunciado "b de burro o *b* de *baca*").

Aproveitei e pesquisei no Spanish Language SE e achei [esta questão](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/12890/why-is-the-b-and-v-pronunciation-inconsistent) sobre o assunto. [Uma das respostas](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/12892) menciona o fenômeno do [Betacismo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betacismo) (artigo até bem completo da Wikipedia) que cita dialetos portugueses do Norte como sendo um dos casos onde ocorre.

Comment: O artigo sobre o betacismo (_v_ e _b_ pronuciados da mesma maneira) é muito interessante, e aponta duas possibilidades para a origem do fenómeno: surgimento paralelo em várias regiões dentro e fora da Ibéria, ou, no caso ibério, tendo origem na Galiza na idade média. Neste última possibilidade, dado que o português e galego ainda não se tinham diferenciado na idade média, teria sido o galaico-português a influenciar o espanhol.

Answer (score 4):

Os *v* e os *b* são "trocados" apenas na oralidade, a escrita não se altera. Isto acontece nas regiões do norte de Portugal, sendo a cidade mais conhecida o Porto.

Não sei até que ponto é que podemos considerar esta pronúncia um dialeto, diria que se define apenas como a *pronúncia do norte*, como já dizia a música.

Comment: Por curiosidade, qual música?

Comment: Pronúncia do Norte, dos GNR - 
[Youtube](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQyCkwAGoVChMI5IbX2bm1xwIVCaSICh2kjgBL&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DteKOeDNLoUY&ei=RJ_UVeTUCYnIogSknYLYBA&usg=AFQjCNHKI4QxYtzc85Hk2zkp4qPbEHeNDA&bvm=bv.99804247,d.cGU)

Comment: @Maslor vê a definição de dialeto.